# Can anyone tell me the name of this cipher please?

Tags: encoding, encode, encryption, substitution

Can anyone tell me the name of this cipher please?

I know it's a simple substitution cipher, I just don't know the name of it.

Cipher Key:

```
help
```

Cipher alphabet:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z
h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|i|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z
```

Text:

```
this is a test
```

Cipher text:

```
tdfs fs h tast
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography and doesn't include a programming problem.

Comment: If it hasn't been named yet I hereby dub it "Lucypher".

Comment: I would say that it is a variation af the Caesar cipher, but the Caesar cipher does not use a key like this.

Comment: @Chris This site is for questions relating to programming and software development (see [Help]). Your question is purely about cryptography and identifying the name of a cipher. You may find more assistance at one of the sites dedicated to these topics (e.g. the crypto site) but check [their help](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) carefully to see if it would be on-topic.

Comment: @Duncan, sorry i didn't realise. The question has now been re-posted on the encryption site here: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/can-anyone-tell-me-the-name-of-this-cipher-please

Comment: Agreed with @Duncan. I think you're better off on the crypto site. Though maybe if you added a little 'how would I implement this in Python most efficiently' we could rescue this question. See my post for an implementation :D

Comment: @cod3monk3y I have requested this question be removed and have posted it already on the cypto site. I have already got scripts in several diferent languages that will encode / decode messages using this cipher. But thanks any way.

Comment: @Chris Sure thing. Good to see you got a response on crypto. Thanks for the vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that just a simple [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher)? You've just moved the 4 letters of "help" to the front and shifted all the remaining letters to the right.

EDIT

Here's an implementation in python as an exercise in lambda, itertools, and star (*) arguments, and wasting time (and perhaps to rescue what could be an interesting discussion on coding ciphers in python):

```
import string
from itertools import izip, count, starmap

def cipher(s,key):
    # characters you want to translate, e.g.
    # 'abcd ... xyz '
    raw = string.ascii_lowercase + ' '

    # cipher with your key, e.g.
    # 'helpabcdfgi...z '
    sub = key + string.translate(raw, None, key)

    # create a dictionary from a character to an index
    # in the original raw value string
    m = dict( izip( raw, count() ) )

    # looks up the index in the map using: starmap(m.get, s)
    # then gets the substitution character: map( lambda i:sub[i], ...)
    # and joins them together
    return ''.join( map( lambda i:sub[i], starmap( m.get, s ) ))
```

And some test code to verify it works:

```
ins = 'this is a test'
outs = cipher(ins, "help") 

print ins,' -> ',outs

exp = "tdfs fs h tast"
if exp == outs:
    print "pass :)"
else:
    print "~~ FAIL ~~", " expected ", exp
```

Output:

```
D:\temp>cipher.py
this is a test  ->  tdfs fs h tast
pass :)
```

Comment: Yes, in short it is just a simple substitution cipher (I would say, a variation of the Caesar cipher) but as this uses a key of sorts I wanted to know if it actually had a name.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer. A Caesar variant, a "Mixed Alphabet" substitution cipher.

Simple yes, but to add mor complexity you could put it in a block like this (becoming a mixture of Mixed Alphabet and Polyalphabetic):

```
  |a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z
------------------------------------------------------
 1|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z
 2|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h
 3|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e
 4|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l
 5|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p
 6|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a
 7|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b
 8|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c
 9|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d
10|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f
11|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g
12|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I
13|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j
14|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k
15|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m
16|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n
17|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o
18|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q
19|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r
20|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s
21|u|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t
22|v|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u
23|w|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v
24|x|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w
25|y|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x
26|z|h|e|l|p|a|b|c|d|f|g|I|j|k|m|n|o|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y
```

This would then be more of a Vigenere Cipher variant rather than a Caesar Cipher variant.

Still with the key:

```
help
```

The same message:

```
this is a test
```

Would become:

```
tfiv kx c hkep
```

Another level of complexity would be to group the letters either all together or into blocks:

```
tfivkxchkep
```

or blocked (3 characters):

```
tfi
vkx
chk
epz

    With an extra z added to make up the missing character.
```